# VBA: How do I get this code to write 3-digit filenames?

Tags: vba, export, image

I'm using the following code to export PNG file from the active PPT file. I find that I need the file names to be THREE digits. Instead of "01.png", "02.png", etc., I need "001.png", "002.png", etc.

Can you help me? I tried

```
sImageName = Format(oSlide.SlideIndex, "000") & ".png"
```

but that didn't work.

Export section code that does work:

```
For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
sImageName = Format(oSlide.SlideIndex, "00") & ".png"
oSlide.Export sImagePath & sImageName, "PNG"
Next oSlide
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What did it do instead of working?  Did you get an error?  What files got created?

Comment: @TimWilliams: It did export, but with filenames "01.png", etc. I think I just learned that it is because I'm testing with PowerPoint 2007, so I need to go test that line I tried on a machine with 2010 on installed. Would there be a fix for 2007 as well?... Thanks!

Comment: there's no difference between 2007 and 2010 as far as this code goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got the solution, the format should be set to "000" instead of "00"

This code runs correctly in Powerpoint 2010

```
Sub Test()
    sImagePath = "C:\Temp\"
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    sImageName = Format(oSlide.SlideIndex, "000") & ".png"
    oSlide.Export sImagePath & sImageName, "PNG"
    Next oSlide
End Sub
```

and produces file names like "001.png"

Comment: Ah, that explains it - I've got PowerPoint 2007 on this test machine! Argh! I'll go test it on a machine with 2010 on it. Thanks!!!

Comment: Yep, that worked perfectly on a machine with 2010 installed. I have no idea why it doesn't work on the 2007 installation, but no matter. THANKS guys!